# SailsJS app on OpenShift cannot start

Tags: node.js, sails.js, openshift

I am new to NodeJS/SailsJS and am trying to work with OpenShift for the very first time. There could be a lot of stupid shortcomings at my end, so please keep my primitive skill level in mind.

I have a SailsJS app that is up and running on Heroku's free service. It is fully functional and in use. However, in order to try out a different, more complex platform and to explore my options, I also want to deploy it on OpenShift.

I followed some tutorials and finally managed to get my code cloned (from a private repo, I ran into some trouble providing SSH access to OpenShift) and built. The build is successful but the deployment/pod shows an error. The logs read as follows

> ```
> Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
> designed for a production environment, as it will leak
> memory, and will not scale past a single process.
> Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
> designed for a production environment, as it will leak
> memory, and will not scale past a single process.
>
>
> npm info lifecycle wopple@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! wopple@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the wopple@0.0.1 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR! /opt/app-root/src/.npm/_logs/2018-04-14T18_38_59_717Z-debug.log
> ```

Log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/opt/rh/rh-nodejs8/root/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/opt/rh/rh-nodejs8/root/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   '-d',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /opt/app-root/src/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
6 info lifecycle wopple@0.0.1~prestart: wopple@0.0.1
7 info lifecycle wopple@0.0.1~start: wopple@0.0.1
8 verbose lifecycle wopple@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle wopple@0.0.1~start: PATH: /opt/rh/rh-nodejs8/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/.bin:/opt/rh/rh-nodejs8/root/usr/bin:/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/.bin/:/opt/app-root/src/.npm-global/bin/:/opt/app-root/src/bin:/opt/app-root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
10 verbose lifecycle wopple@0.0.1~start: CWD: /opt/app-root/src
11 silly lifecycle wopple@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node app.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle wopple@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle wopple@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: wopple@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/opt/rh/rh-nodejs8/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/
npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/rh/rh-nodejs8/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/
npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
15 verbose pkgid wopple@0.0.1
16 verbose cwd /opt/app-root/src
17 verbose Linux 3.10.0-693.15.2.el7.x86_64
18 verbose argv "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs8/root/usr/bin/node" "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs8/root/usr/bin/npm" "run" "-d" "start"
19 verbose node v8.9.4
20 verbose npm  v5.6.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error wopple@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the wopple@0.0.1 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I believe there are ample OpenShift professionals here to help figure this thing out. Do comment if something else needs to be shared from the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the OpenShift S2I builder for NodeJS, or have you tried rolling your own image and are deploying that? You can try running ``oc debug dc/yourappname``. That will give you a shell from which you can run the command it displays as the entrypoint command. That will try and start the application. When it fails, check that log it mentions to see if it shows anything more.

Comment: About deployment, I created a new application through the web console, picked NodeJS from the catalog and in the Git repo field, entered my repo URL (and added the SSH key as a secret, following a tutorial for private repos). I'm not too well versed with the OpenShift terminology, though. So I'm unsure if I used the S2I buider or _rolled my own image_ here.

Comment: I'll try running the terminal command and revert.

Comment: So I first ran `oc debug dc/project-name` and in the terminal thereafter, I ran `node app.js`, judging by this line in my _package.json_ file: `..."start": "node app.js"...`. The Sails were lifted and in the web console, I could see a new running pod called *wopple-sails-debug*. This one is running successfully, but I can't figure how to send requests to this to test.

Comment: I don't want you to run the command from ``package.json``. I want you to run the command which ``oc debug`` output on the screen when it first starts. That command does all the same steps as when started where as your command doesn't. You can't interact with the pod easily since this is a debug pod. It isn't exposed by a service or route.

Comment: Oh, my bad. It gave me this command: `container-entrypoint /usr/libexec/s2i/run` and I ran it in the console. I got pretty much the same output as in my question. A [log file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10JEeNEJeOMe_KwX2SGmKX94Bp4SyJwuRrgvLu9-tTgc/edit?usp=sharing) was also generated.

Comment: It is better to edit your question and include relevant parts of that log in it, rather than link to it on another site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169020/discussion-between-slashg-and-graham-dumpleton).